# Is there a tool to create repo manifest file with SHA based on current work directory?

Tags: android, python, git, repository, repo

I'm using repo, which is used by Android project, to manage my project.

Is there a tool to create repo manifest file with SHA based on current work directory as the following?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
<remote fetch="git://address.com/" name="origin" review="review.address.com"/>
<default remote="origin" revision="ics-something" sync-j="4"/>
<manifest-server url="http://manifests.address.com:8000"/>
<!-- sniff -->
<project name="platform/frameworks/base" path="frameworks/base"
       revision="ecb41a77411358d385e3fde5b4e98a5f3d9cfdd5"/>
<project name="platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth" path="packages/apps/Bluetooth"
       revision="621bae79f1a250e443eb83d1f473c533bea493dc"/>
<!-- sniff -->
</manifest>
```

I mean to create a new manifest file base the current manifest, and the project revision value is the HEAD SHA of projects in current work directory.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 24):

The `repo manifest` command creates manifest files with fixed SHA-1s based on the current workspace.

```
repo manifest -r -o my-manifest.xml
```

Comment: thanks. I tried the command, by it do not output SHA. After reference to the help message, I can use ` repo manifest -r --suppress-upstream-revision -o my-manifest.xml ` to output SHA, but the path field in manifest was lost.

Comment: That's probably because of `--suppress-upstream-revision`. I'd forgotten about `-r` and I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: `--suppress-upstream-revision` only suppress the upstream attribute of project in manifest file, Besides the SHA-1s, I also want the path attribute to be output as the original one.